# how to access programmatically to "print preview and print" page in Office Word 2010

Tags: c#, printing, word-automation, word-2010

I am writing a medical program (with C# Language) which has a relation with Microsoft Office Word 2010. In Word 2010 there is a page "Print Preview and Print" which you can access by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. After I launch Office Word, I want to see "Print Preview and Print" but instead I see the old print preview from Office 2007/2003, which means I don't know how to access this page from office com objects.

The code I've tried:

```
oWordDoc.PrintPreview();
_oWord.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) to do the same as the hotkey <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

```
SendKeys.Send("^P");
```

Comment: When i used SendKeys.Send method , exception returns "SendKeys Cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling windows messages. Either change the application to handle message, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method". So After that i change the send Method to SendWait and i use small "p" letter instead of capital "P" and it worked so thank you for your fast response.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int dialogResult = wordApp.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint].Show(ref missing);
if (dialogResult == 1)
{
    oWordDoc.PrintOut(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                      ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

Comment: that methods brings up the old Print Dialog from word 2003 ,but thank you for your fast response.