# Interop.Word print preview dialog for office 2010/2013

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

In my application I have word template with tags which are later replaced using `interop.word (find/replace)` and then sent to print using print preview dialog:
`Interop.Word.Application.Dialogs[WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint]`

On a result of a dialog I am printing or closing the document.

For office 2003 and 2007 this is working absolutely fine, but in office 2010 later print preview dialog is absolutely different.

I've found related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365007/how-to-access-programmatically-to-print-preview-and-print-page-in-office-word) but I need to grab dialog result so that i could further do print or close the doc.

Is there any workaround or soultions for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the future reference posting answer to my own question. Finally I could figure it out.

Following code is working with any version of Word fine. While dialog is open application freezes and waits for a result just as another dialogs.

The only moment is it allows to choose appropriate printer only, but does not show preview.

```
             _doc.Activate();
             _wordApp.Visible = true;

             var dialogResult = _wordApp.Dialogs[WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint].Show();

             if (dialogResult == 1)
                 _doc.PrintOut();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that will hopefully help you get closer that I wrote for Interop for Office 2000 years ago. I tested it with Office 2007 and it works, but don't have 2010 to test atm.

I'm assuming you already have the Interop references.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace printdialog
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Word.ApplicationClass WordApp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create Word Instance
            WordApp = OpenWordApplication();

             //Show Word
            WordApp.Visible = true;

            //Open a Word Doc
            OpenWordDocument(WordApp, "c:\\test.docx");


            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to Print?", "PrintPreview", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            switch (result)
            {
                case DialogResult.OK:
                    {
                        WordApp.PrintPreview = true;
                        //if preview call above doesn't work try the call below 
                        //WordApp.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintPreview;
                        break;
                    }
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    {
                        CloseWordApplication(WordApp);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method returns a Word.ApplicationClass Object.
        /// Tested with the Microsoft 9.0 Object Library ( COM )
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Word.ApplicationClass Object</returns>
        public static Word.ApplicationClass OpenWordApplication()
        {
            try
            {
                Word.ApplicationClass WordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();
                return (WordApp);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //show the user the error message
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

                return (null);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method returns a Word.Document Object from the File Location and loads it into the 
        /// Word.ApplicationClass Object. Basically it means it opens a previously saved word document. 
        /// Tested with the Microsoft 9.0 Object Library ( COM )
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="WordApp">This is the Word.ApplicationClass Object. It is the Object that contains
        /// the Word Application</param>
        /// <param name="FileLocation">This is the File Location for the Word Document you would like to open.
        /// Note that this is the full long name of the File Location.</param>
        /// <returns>Word.Document Object</returns>
        public static Word.Document OpenWordDocument(Word.ApplicationClass WordApp, string FileLocation)
        {
            try
            {
                object j_FileName = FileLocation;
                object j_Visible = true;
                object j_ReadOnly = false;
                object j_NullObject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                // Let's open the document
                Word.Document WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref j_FileName,
                ref j_NullObject, ref j_ReadOnly, ref j_NullObject, ref j_NullObject,
                ref j_NullObject, ref j_NullObject, ref j_NullObject, ref j_NullObject,
                ref j_NullObject, ref j_NullObject, ref j_Visible);

                return (WordDoc);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //show the user the error message
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

                return (null);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method closes the Word.ApplicationClass instance that is sent
        /// as a parameter. Releasing the COM Object by Marshal seems
        /// to properly dispose of the Object.
        /// Tested with the Microsoft 9.0 Object Library ( COM )
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="WordApp"></param>
        public static void CloseWordApplication(Word.ApplicationClass WordApp)
        {
            try
            {
                object j_SaveChanges = false;
                object j_NullObject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                WordApp.Quit(ref j_SaveChanges, ref j_NullObject, ref j_NullObject);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WordApp);
                WordApp = null;

                System.GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //show the user the error message
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

            }
        }

    }
}
```